# How to end a For Loop via user input

Tags: java, stopwatch

can u help with 
this stopwatch?
I want that after writting "0" program will end. 
Stopwatch is working but i dont now how to stop.
Thank for your answer.

```
package stopky;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stopky {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);     
    System.out.println("Stlačte 0 pre začatie stopiek."); // "Press 0 for start 
    int start=sc.nextInt();
    if (start==0) {

    for(int hodiny = 0; hodiny < 24; hodiny++) //hours
    {           
        for(int minuty = 0; minuty < 60; minuty++) //minutes
        {   
           for(int sekundy = 0; sekundy < 60; sekundy++) //seconds
           {
               for(int ms = 0; ms < 1000; ms++) //miliseconds
                   try {Thread.sleep(1);} catch (Exception e) {}

               {

                   System.out.println(hodiny + ":" + minuty + ":" + sekundy  );

               }
           }
        }
    }
}
    sc.close();


}
```

}

Comment: It's not that easy. You can't stop the program by just typing something as you will only be able to scan for another input after the current task is completed. (Stopwatch stopps counting) You could however solve this problem by using multithreading.

Comment: `for(int ms = 0; ms < 1000; ms++) //miliseconds
                   try {Thread.sleep(1);} catch (Exception e) {}` can be replaced with `try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (Exception e) {}` or even for better readability `try{TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);} catch (Exception e) {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a for-loop want to quit you need only a "break;" ,
so best you have a variable is always watched by whether they are "0", and if so then any for loop executes a break; out. To Example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stopky {

    private volatile static int check = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Stlačte 0 pre začatie stopiek."); // "Press 0 for start
        int start = sc.nextInt();
        if (start == 0) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (check != 0 && sc.hasNextInt())
                        check = sc.nextInt();
                }
            }).start();
            for (int hodiny = 0; hodiny < 24; hodiny++) //hours
            {
                for (int minuty = 0; minuty < 60; minuty++) //minutes
                {
                    for (int sekundy = 0; sekundy < 60; sekundy++) //seconds
                    {
                        for (int ms = 0; ms < 1000; ms++) //miliseconds
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        {
                            if (check == 0)
                                break;
                            System.out.println(hodiny + ":" + minuty + ":" + sekundy);
                        }
                        if (check == 0)
                            break;
                    }
                    if (check == 0)
                        break;
                }
                if (check == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `check != "0"`, `check == "0"` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: I've just changed the code from a string to an int. This should make it easier to handle.

Comment: I would also make `check` `volatile`, otherwise threads can use its cached version and ignore its change.

Comment: Hm Is it true that otherwise a small delay from interruption can occur, but otherwise something really should not happen in the case.